# Unable to access AWS Elastic Beanstalk site

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've created an AWS EB web app, .Net Core on Linux, sample app, with the aws-elasticbeanstalk-service role as the service role and an EC2 Instance profile I've created. With that in place, I just skip to review and create the resource.

The environment deploys successfully, as far as I can tell, but then the application is not available at the URL. If I deploy without the instance profile, the deployment fails.

It's possible the instance profile doesn't have some permission the system needs, but I would expect the deployment to fail if that were the case. I can confirm that it does have the AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk permission.

I've checked the inbound rules for the instance security group - it's port 80 0.0.0.0/0, which should allow everything.

Health status is "pending", and then eventually "No Data". I've tried multiple platforms, same result. I'm out of ideas. Seems kind of weird that it wouldn't just work out of the box.

Comment: Are VPC, Load balancer configured properly?

Comment: I'm not using a VPC, and just took the default of a single instance.

Comment: It's crazy. This is the most elemental possible question about Elastic Beanstalk, and no one can answer it. Is EB just plain broken?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Service roles, instance profiles, and user policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts-roles.html), please check the following instance profile permissions:
`AWSElasticBeanstalkWebTier`
`AWSElasticBeanstalkWorkerTier`
`AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker`

This should work with the sample application ([dotnet-core-linux.zip](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/samples/dotnet-core-linux.zip))

I recommend you read this for further development: [Tutorial: Deploying an ASP.NET core application with Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-core-tutorial.html)
This to better understand ElasticBeanstalk: [Elastic Beanstalk concepts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/concepts.html)

Comment: That was the exact problem, It was missing `AWSElasticBeanstalkMulticontainerDocker` permission on EC2 instance profile.

Thanks for the answer!